# Bitcoin wallet carving

Tags: wallet-recovery, wallet.dat

I've been file carving old drives and found several bitcoin Magic number headers. My question is does the wallet.dat file have a footer? Or how can I calculate the proper size of the Berkeley db file so I can cut and paste the hex into a new file.

Thanks,
Justin